# C# Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server

Apologies in advance if I missed an answer to this somewhere but I wasn't quite finding it anywhere. So I'm building an application that scans PDF's of service orders our company gets, parses it, and inserts it into a SQL DB. The problem is at the end of this code. It successfully :

- saves the original pdf in the proper folder
- scans the pdf and parses it
- inserts the correct data into the service order table
- grabs PK of service order just created as we need that for the next batch of inserts

Here is where it gets hung up with a Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

I foreach through all the instruments as there are multiples per Service Order, but it is erroring on this somewhere. to be clear I put a break point on the insert statement and all of the data is good and in the proper format ("string" int)

I feel like its in my connection maybe?

Anyways, thanks in advance for the help.

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PDF/") + filename);

// Now we parse the PDF by creating a new ServiceOrder object and parsing from it.
ServiceOrder so = new ServiceOrder();

// Make sure we load the PDF from the correct path on the server
so.LoadPDF(Server.MapPath("~/PDF/") + filename);

String strConnString = "Data Source=127.0.0.0;Initial Catalog=SOMECATALOG;User ID=SOMEUSER;Password=SOMEPASSWORD";

// Insert Into Service Orders Table
string defaultdate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strQuery = "insert into TServiceOrders (strServiceOrderNo, intStatusCodeID, strCustomerName, strCustomerNo, strCustomerAddress1, strCustomerAddress2, strCustomerAddress3, intRepID, strServiceDescription, strServiceRequestDate, strServiceOrderDate, strNotes) values ('" 
    + so.ServiceOrderNumber.ToString() + "', 2, '" 
    + so.CustomerContactName.ToString() + "', '" 
    + so.CustomerNumber.ToString() + "', '" 
    + so.CustomerContactAddress1.ToString() + "', '" 
    + so.CustomerContactAddress2.ToString() + "', '" 
    + so.CustomerContactAddress3.ToString() + "', 1, '', '" 
    + defaultdate + "', '" + defaultdate + "', '')";

SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

// Grabbing latest primary key od service order just added for next instrument inserts
int lastid = 999999;
String strPKquery = "select top 1 intServiceOrderID from TServiceOrders order by intServiceOrderID desc";
SqlDataReader rdr = null;
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(strPKquery, conn2);
try
{
    conn2.Open();
    rdr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        lastid = (int)rdr["intServiceOrderID"];
    }

}
finally
{
    if (rdr != null)
    {
        rdr.Close();
    }

    if (conn2 != null)
    {
        conn2.Close();
    }
}

// Insert Into Service Instruments Tables           
SqlConnection conn3 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
conn3.Open();
foreach (ServiceInstrument sin in so.ServiceInstruments)
{
    string sim = "";
    sim = sin.ServiceInstrumentModel;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sim))
    {
        sim = "";
    }
    else
    {
        sim = sin.ServiceInstrumentModel.ToString();
    }
    string sid = "";
    sid = sin.ServiceInstrumentDescription;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sid))
    {
        sid = "";
    }
    else
    {
        sid = sin.ServiceInstrumentDescription.ToString();
    }
    string sis = "";
    sis = sin.ServiceInstrumentSerial;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sis))
    {
        sis = "";
    }
    else
    {
        sis = sin.ServiceInstrumentSerial.ToString();
    }
    string sih = "";
    sih = sin.ServiceInstrumentHandle;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sih))
    {
        sih = "";
    }
    else
    {
        sih = sin.ServiceInstrumentHandle.ToString();
    }
    string sip = "";
    sip = sin.ServiceInstrumentParentAsset;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(sip))
    {
        sip = "";
    }
    else
    {
        sip = sin.ServiceInstrumentParentAsset.ToString();
    }                        
    String strQuery3 = "insert into TServiceInstruments values ('" + sim.ToString() + "', '" + sid.ToString() + "', '" + sis.ToString() + "', '" + sih.ToString() + "', " + sip.ToString() + ", " + lastid + ")";
    SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(strQuery3, conn3);                       
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();                        
}
conn3.Close();
```

Comment: Did I miss where you said which line throws the exception?

Comment: Post entire exception.

Comment: Also, use parameters instead of concatenating strings together. That's not just a SQL injection vulnerability, it's a bug farm. Also there's no need to gum it up with all those `ToString()` calls. C# can figure out how to stringify things.

Comment: Also, I would use `ExecuteScalar()` rather than `ExecuteReader()` here since you're only returning one record.

Comment: Remember the days when .PDF was a format that was used when you didn't want your data parsed?

Comment: sorry, it makes it through everything until the bottom  String strQuery3 = "insert into TServiceInstruments values ('" + sim.ToString() + "', '" + sid.ToString() + "', '" + sis.ToString() + "', '" + sih.ToString() + "', " + sip.ToString() + ", " + lastid + ")";

Comment: *"itmakes it through everything until the bottom"* -- please, please, **put a comment on the exact precise specific line where it throws the exception**, and include the entire text of the exception, all of it. Playing guessing games with people makes them very impatient and frustrated, and they lose interest in helping you.

Comment: should i not open the connection before the foreach and close it afterwards?

Comment: @user3282297 You should add exception message text to question, and tell us which exactly line in the code is throwing the exception. I'm skeptical that the string concatenation is throwing a SqlException.

Comment: It doesn't tell me which line the exception is on, it just shows up in the output not in the code area

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in System.Data.dll

Comment: What output? What are you talking about? Run it in the debugger. The debugger. Put in a breakpoint and step through it in the debugger. Tell us what line it throws the exception on, and give us the text of the exception message.

Comment: that's all it's giving me down in the output, its not directly flagging anything

Comment: So you're telling me that when you step through the code, in the debugger, every line of code you showed us executes successfully without throwing an exception. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: yes I put break points all over the place making sure everything was getting pulled in correctly and everything works and inserts properly until the very last insert and when I put a break on it everything looks good as well as far as proper data in columns etc. but it's not inserting and giving me that exception but not telling me what line like it usually does. Sorry but I've never used stack trace, I'm still learning.

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, that will show you how to break the debugger. You then have to explore the Exception window and view the Stack Trace, Message, and Inner Exceptions.

Comment: Do you get some kind of "Exception was unhandled" popup when the exception is thrown? Different versions of Visual Studio will do this in slightly different ways. Find a "View Detail" or "View Details" thing on that dialog to click on. You should be able to find exception details there. There will be `Message` and `StackTrace` properties. Those are important.

Comment: I was missing single quotes on " + sip.ToString() + ". none of the System.Data.Sql stuff was checked in my execption settings

Answer (score 3):

1. When writing insert statements you should always specify the column names. This will protect the code from changes in the order of the columns in the table schema.
2. You are not using parameters in your sql statements, this **leaves your code vulnerable to Sql Injection**.
3. You should use `using` statements around your SqlConnection instances to ensure they are closed even when an Exception occurs.
4. Your logic is very difficult to follow, split your code until methods with meaningful names instead of having 1 "God" method that does everything.

If you follow those guidelines the problem will most likely solve itself in your refactoring.

#### Update Code Fragment

*Note that you should always specify the correct types for your columns and the length if applicable. Also pass the actual value and never the string value.*

```
const String strQuery3 = "INSERT INTO TServiceInstruments (sim, sid, sis, sih, sip, lid) VALUES (@sim, @sid, @sis, @sih, @sip, @lid)";

using(var conection = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(strQuery3, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sim", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = sim});
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = sid});
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sis", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = sis});
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sih", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = sih});
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sip", SqlDbType.Int){Value = sip});
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@lid", SqlDbType.Int){Value = lid});
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();          
}
```

Final note: You really need to learn how to read Exceptions and this includes the Stack Trace which points directly to the line in the call stack where the Exception originated. If you can understand this then debugging becomes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this doesn't deserve to be an answer, but I'm trying to build some reputation, so here goes :).

I suspect that your error lies in the "insert into TServiceInstruments ..." statement. Namely, you are giving the table more (or less) columns. As a good practice, always specify the columns, like this:

```
insert into TServiceInstruments (column1, column2, column3)
values (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Add a PSA about SQL injection and I'll remove the downvote.  Your answer would be much improved with parameterized query code...

Comment: thanks, but there are 7 columns in my table and it's autoincrement so 6 inserts. I tried to embed some pictures but it wont let me. when I put a break on it and check it out the statement looks fine with the proper data to insert